# Computing conditional probabilities in a Bayesian Network with AND

Tags: statistics, probability, bayesian-networks

Take this network: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHnqk.png

How would I calculate

> P(J|S∩E)

Is this correct?

```
P(J|S∩E) = P(J|S) * P(J|E) ?
```

I don't understand how they can be given since they are not connected directly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I have to apply the Bayes Theorem with the additional condition.

https://dzone.com/storage/temp/8482917-screen-shot-2018-03-14-at-40747-pm.png

> P(J|S∩E) = P(J∩S∩E)/P(S∩E)

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/conditional-probability-and-bayes-theorem

and

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176315/conditional-probability-of-event-a-given-events-b-and-c-occur-events-b-and-c-ar

Comment: Hmm, what numerical result did you get? I am looking at the graph and thinking that, given E, S and J are now independent. So, I'm thinking, P(J|S, E) = P(J|E) = 0.8 as given in the problem data. Does that match the result you got?